# Tried to convert VB code to C# but error occurred

Tags: c#

I did convert the `VB` code to below `C#` code, but error occurred. I am getting error in `Strings.InStr` and `Strings.Mid`.

```
    sHeadingNm = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1).NameLocal;  
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sHeadingNm)) {  
    nPos = Strings.InStr(1, sHeadingNm, "1");  
    if (nPos > 0)  
        sHeadingNm = Strings.Mid(sHeadingNm, 1, nPos - 1);  
}  

//=======================================================  
//Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)  
//Conversion powered by NRefactory.  
//Twitter: @telerik  
//Facebook: facebook.com/telerik  
//=======================================================
```

Please help me...

Comment: What *is* the error you get?

Comment: Reading the error message would be a good first step.  For starters, what is this `Strings` class?  Is that something in VB that isn't in C#?  When translating between languages, don't focus on word-for-word translations.  Determine what this piece of code *does* and implement the *functionality* in the desired language.  What does this code *do*?

Comment: `Styles(wdStyleHeading1)` is probably a dictionary so it should be `Styles[wdStyleHeading1]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# equivalents of method you've used:

`Strings.InStr` has equivalent of [String.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx)

`Strings.Mid` has equivalent of [String.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You should say .NET equivalent. `InStr` and `Mid` exist to offer some compatibility with VB6. All .NET languages can call the `String` classes

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the C# equivalent functions something like this:

nPos = sHeadingNm.IndexOf('1');

sHeadingNm = sHeadingNm.Substring( 1, nPos - 1);

Answer (score 1):

Your problem must be that `Strings.InStr` and `Strings.Mid` are not standard methods in C#, but in VB.net. You should add probably  `using Microsoft.VisualBasic` in order to use them, although i'd recommend to use C# equivalent methods.

Answer (score 1):

Better stated, you let the Telerik converter convert the code.   Code converters can't safely assume that library and function calls which exist in one language do not exist in the other; for all they know, your destination code has a custom library that mimics the behavior of functions only present in the source language.  Additionally, most functions in VB that are VB-only are 1-based, not 0-based as in the rest of .Net.

For this reason, you don't get an automatic conversion of `Strings.InStr` to `String.IndexOf`.  You also won't see Strings.Mid to String.Substring.   Code looking for a "0" to return from `Strings.Instr` or `Strings.Mid` because nothing was found will break, as "0" is now the first index in a successful search.   You actually *need* the ensuing errors to determine where you need to adjust your code to look for the proper response (i.e., -1 on a search with no results).